# Jquery PHP - How to handle login callback on same page?

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

Simply, my website allows users to login.

```
$('#login').click(function() {
    var user = $('#username').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();
    $.post('authorize.php', { username: user, password: pass }, function(data) {
        //??
    });
});
```

`authorize.php` verifies credentials assuring a proper login. But now what? Do I use Jquery to `$.show` a hidden object, or do I load the new content from a PHP page with `$.get` or `$.load`? I'm uneasy on using `$.show` because elements will be loaded into the DOM regardless of a proper login. All of this takes place on the same page. Which of these two options is better practice? Or is there another?

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ajax request for login it is not good practice. Anyway there are three ways:

1. You can add some "blank" object into DOM without first, last names and
   other dynamic or important information and fill it and show as soon as user
   logins.
2. Send dom object as response from authrize.php
3. Do not use ajax for login :)

Answer (score 0):

Have authorize.php send the hidden object as data in case of a successful login and then display the data wherever you want. 
$.show is not a good practice for the reason you mentioned above.